# How can i move a bunch of folder from subfolders to another folder

Tags: windows, file, explorer, file-move

I have a dictionary filled with folders that got a name with its id for each like the following picture[image: The folders am talking about]
so each of those folders contain a folder called mods and inside the folder called mods there is another folder with the name of each mod like the following [image: the inside of mods folder]
i want to be able to move all the folders like BRDM-2 and 74amgeneralM151A2 to a main folder called mods putting in mind that in each folder has a different name so what do i do?